# How to change column name in laravel?

Tags: laravel-5

I am a beginner of laravel. Now, I would like to retrieve data from database using this code:

```
$data = Model::select('col1', 'col2', 'col3')->get();
```

and return $data to another view.

However, I would like to change the name of the columns. For example, changing col1 to column_1 before returning the array to the view. How can I change the column names? I am now using laravel 5.5. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `selectRaw()` method.

```
$data = Model::selectRaw('col1 as c1, col2 as c2, col3 as c3')->get();
```

Note that, all columns must be in the same string value.

Comment: Yes, this is working. Thank you. Additionally, if you want to change the name of only one field, with all fields. 
---
`return Users::selectRaw('*, erp_code user_erp_code')->where('id', 1)->first();`

Answer (score 1):

You can use accessors to work with such attributes, but there's no way to query them this way with core eloquent.
But fear not! Use this package https://github.com/jarektkaczyk/eloquence and you can easily achieve what you want (Mappable in particular):

```
// collection model 
protected $maps =['col1' => 'column_1','col2' => 'column_2',...];

// then you can do this:
$Col = Col::whereId($id)->first();// calls WHERE id = ? sql

$Col->col1; // column_1 column
$Col->col2; // column_2 column
$Col->col2 = 'different name'; // set mutator works as well
```

It's in heavy development and *currently* *select* *is not yet supported*, but it's a matter of a day or two, select support has been pushed already.

In your model do not forget

```
use Sofa\Eloquence\Eloquence; //base trait 
use Sofa\Eloquence\Mappable; // extension trait
```

and then inside your class

```
 use Eloquence, Mappable;
```

This package is super! saves a lot of time.

Comment: my dude, QueryBuilder already has selectRaw method, why you use external classes ?

Comment: If you need to map in model level my approach is helpful, assume you need toArray() method, then you don't have to manually map all columns and once you do it in the model you can use it in any other place you want.